# Remove/rename package Wiki page

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

last week I published some ROS packages into an indexed repo and started working on the Wiki pages.
After I finished with all the package documentation it turned out that I have to rename the package and do some refactoring (not my idea of course) so I did all the necessary software modifications but what about the wiki pages and tutorials I created?

My primary solution was to create new pages and add the sources from the old ones after a bit of refactoring.

The question is: is there a more appropriate way to do this?
Also how can I remove the "deprecated" wiki pages?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37899/remove/rename-package-wiki-page/) by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 358 on 2012-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Duplicate of [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/33571/moving-wiki-pages/).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0